# Cannot access defaults field of Properties

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I am having trouble deploying my application to tomcat. It was working before, but i formated my computer and it stopped working.

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.academiadecodigo.javabank</groupId>
<artifactId>javabank-step10-show-delete</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Java Bank Webapp</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.196</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version> 3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSR-301/3 validation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>

    <finalName>Java Bank</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>10</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                <server>tomcat</server>
                <path>/javabank</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is the error:

1. Error injecting constructor, java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Cannot access defaults field of Properties
   at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.(Unknown Source)
   while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo

I have tried:

https://www.programmersought.com/article/85431846620/

https://www.programmersought.com/article/31114978502/

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/dependency-info.html

Deleting the .m2 folder

"And" all the solutions on stackOverflow

I know this is not the best formulated question but i dont know what else to do...

Comment: I would update the dependencies - starting with tomcat version

Comment: Try adding the `maven-war-plugin` explicitly (cf. [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/plugin-info.html)) as the [default binding](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/default-bindings.html) is quite old.

Comment: O M G ! This solution is exactly like one i tried, but with a diferent version... fml... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 13):

I followed instructions in [Comment by Piotr P. Karwasz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67221463/cannot-access-defaults-field-of-properties#comment118824822_67221463). That worked out fine! The problem with one of the solutions i tried was the version number.

Solution:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/plugin-info.html